# Sharepoint 2013 site in Tablet

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

Some of users wanted to access the SharePoint 2013 Document Library and list in Tablet device. The issue is some of the ribbon button and text for example "checkout" & "checkin" in Document library is very small and it's not so easy for the user using touching screen. What is different are Options to make big enough like edit document.

[image: DocLib Ribbon Menu]

Comment: Looping the page is the best solution

Comment: What you mean by Looping ?.

Comment: why not use the SharePoint App on the tablet?

Comment: That's not possible.